# Header file not found when building under cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin, preprocessor, openexr

I am trying to build a certain library under cygwin (OpenEXR), and I get the following error:

```
b44ExpLogTable.cpp:52:18: error: half.h: No such file or directory
```

`half.h` is referenced using `#include <half.h>`, and is actually a part of another library I successfully run `make/make install` on previously.

The question is -- when using `#include` with `<>`, where the preprocessor expects to find the specified file?

(I have just found it in `/usr/local/include/OpenEXR`, but I have no idea why preprocessor cannot).

*Update:* I have also found:

#### Makefile

```
ILMBASE_CXXFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include/OpenEXR
```

#### Makefile.am

```
INCLUDES = @ILMBASE_CXXFLAGS@ \
       -I$(top_builddir)  \
       -I$(top_srcdir)/config
```

This actually decreased my understanding of what the problem may be.

*Update 2:* So, by redefining some variables in makefile I found out that instead of `$(CXXCOMPILE)` make seems to run `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)`, with `CXXFLAGS` being just `-g -O2`. Ok, I have no idea how it manages to run `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)` if this combination in not used anywhere in the makefile except in `$(CXXCOMPILE)` which is not run. I can add my `-I` to `CXXFLAGS` but I have a feeling that a lot more additions will be required, so I would prefer to find a root cause of the problem.

(I am not sure whether it is a Super User or Stack Overflow question, because my developer skills in C++/Linux are almost non-existent.)

Comment: probably fine to be stackoverflow.  I think superuser is more about IT-like problems, but don't quote me on that :)

Comment: What version of OpenEXR are you trying to build? I was able to set `CPPFLAGS` correctly when building openexr-1.7.0.

Comment: @Jack Kelly, 1.7.0, but I think it is a openexr/cygwin problem, not just an openexr problem. were you able to build it in cygwin?

Comment: I don't have access to a Cygwin environment, I'm sorry. Did you try setting `CPPFLAGS` through the `configure` script?

Answer (score 1):

Additional include directories are usually specified in `CPPFLAGS`. Try running `./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/OpenEXR` and re-running `make`.

Comment: If this is insufficient (more errors are encountered), see this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/users/1268131/kai-ninomiya](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1268131/kai-ninomiya)

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow get `-I/usr/local/include/OpenEXR` added to the compiler command line.  That might be a simple matter of doing:

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/OpenEXR make
```

Comment: Just tried this (and also CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS since it seems to be a cpp), but it didn't work -- produces exactly the same error.

Comment: Just noticed make shows actual command: `g++ -g -O2    b44ExpLogTable.cpp   -o b44ExpLogTable`. Not sure if -I should be here as well, but it isn't.

Comment: @Andrey Shchekin: Yes, that's where you need the `-I` option(s) to appear.  Exactly how to do that depends on how the specific project's Makefile works.